# How do I run containerized Cypress runner against containerized server?

Tags: docker, nginx, cypress

I'm trying to run Cypress tests against containerized Nginx:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
7c3efd24e6e6   tdd_nginx      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 minutes ago   Up 19 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           tdd_nginx_1
```

from official [docs](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/) I learned I can use `docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e -e CYPRESS_baseUrl=host.docker.internal cypress/included:7.7.0`

[Here](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/run-cypress-included-from-docker-container/) I learned about `host.docker.internal` which is how supposedly Cypress knows to look for `localhost` in a particular container.

Nginx container has exposed port 80 so I've tried `-e CYPRESS_baseUrl=host.docker.internal:80` as well as without specifying port as port 80 is a fallback port in most cases.

error output:

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > http://host.docker.internal:80

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
We will try connecting to it 1 more time...

Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.

Please start this server and then run Cypress again.
```

Moving the env variable into `cypress.json` made no difference:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "host.docker.internal",
  "video": false
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `CYPRESS_BASE_URL`?

Comment: `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Changed the `cypress.json` to:

```
{
  "CYPRESS_BASE_URL": "host.docker.internal",
  "video": false
}
```

parsing `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` as env variable didn't help but putting it into the file did the trick. Strangely, it makes difference.

Thanks goes to @jonrsharpe